# Do I tell another manager that one of their team members was doing work he should not?

Tags: management, team

I am manager of team A. Before I became manager Steve (not his real name) belonged to team A and enjoyed the work.

Steve was moved to team B. He dislikes the work performed by team B.

Last week I discovered that, without discussing the matter with anyone, Steve was continuing to perform tasks for my team. He is friends with many people in the organisation, he did excellent work when on my team, and after moving he fostered connections rather than sever them.

I severed them.

But what I've not done is tell his manager that this occurred. It's not my job to point out to Steve's manager that they are failing to manage Steve effectively. To put it another way, if my team B colleague didn't work out over a period of weeks that Steve wasn't doing his job that's not my business.

Or is it.

Should I tell the other manager what happened?

Edit: I missed a crucial detail. His team - even with him added to it - remains severely under-resourced which is causing significant pain for stakeholders.

Comment: If the situation were reversed, would you want another manager to let you know about the behavior of one of your people? If your company has a time tracking system, is Steve mis-charging his time in order to conceal his work for his old team? If so, that compounds the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I do think you should have a discussion with Steve's new boss.

However it should be a positive one - very positive.

Steve did great work for you and is probably still doing work for your team because he feels comfortable doing it and I am guessing he does not have critical things (or maybe anything) to do with team B yet.

Think about your company before you think about Steve doing right or wrong.  He probably has good intentions.  If he is doing work for your team that is still benefiting your company (and your team) then there is really no harm being done - just a little misalignment.

My conversations with his new manager would be first thanking him for letting Steve finish up some tasks for your group after he moved.  And then let him know that Steve did a great job.  If you are concerned that Steve will bother your team you can hint that Steve still spends a lot of time with old teammates but walk the line of being too nice about Steve.

I have managed tech teams for years.  I have had a Steve 2-3 times.  I love Steves!  Do not get Steve in trouble or you are just evil.

Answer (score 3):

Without understanding how you "severed" Steve's ties with Team A I would first recommend talking with Steve about why he's doing work for your team. Perhaps their is a gap or issue within Team A that Steve is addressing by performing excellent work for his former friends/colleagues.

I'd first make sure Team A is stable before managing Team B. If Steve is completing his Team B work then I'm not sure there is a large upside for you alerting his manager unless there is a time-card/pay issue involved.

Answer (score -1):

> Should I tell the other manager what happened?

It is Steve's job to express his interests and problems to his manager. You, talking on behalf of him to his manager would be considered unsolicited.

> It's not my job to point out to Steve's manager that they are failing
>   to manage Steve effectively.

Exactly, you've just answered your question there.

However, as you seem to care for Steve personally, you can suggest Steve to talk to his manager about his problems and the reasons behind them.